# How to write search query for the below MongoDB query scenario in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Considering below 5 parameters:

1. Mutual friends
2. Home Town
3. Current City
4. School
5. company

I need to write a search query that search should start with matching with all parameters which will get accurate results.

- consider at-least 4 parameters
- If not then consider at-least 3 parameters
- If not then consider at-least 2 parameters
- If not then consider at-least 1 parameter
- If not then shows all.

How to write search query for the above scenario in C#?

I used the following code

```
public class UserDetails
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public Registration RegistrationDetails { get; set; }
     }
public class Registration
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
var collection = database.GetCollection<UserDetails>("UserInfo");
                var agg = collection.Aggregate().Project(p => new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    matchValue =
                    (p.RegistrationDetails.FirstName == search ? 1 : 0) +
                    (p.RegistrationDetails.LastName == search ? 1 : 0)
                })
                .Group(new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, BsonValue>
                {
                    {"_id", BsonValue.Create("$matchValue")},
                    {"ids", new BsonDocument("$push", new 
                     BsonDocument("item","$Id"))}
                }))
                .Sort(new BsonDocument("_id", BsonValue.Create(-1)))
                .Limit(1)
                .Unwind("ids")
                .Project(new BsonDocument("_id", "$ids.item"));
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please provide some example data and desired result, and also some codes that you have tried so far -HTH ;).

Comment: @shA.t Let take a user model consisting of home town, current city, school, company parameters. Now i want to give the search results if all the home town, current city, school, company parameters matched results , if no results found i need to take at least 3 parameters matched results, if no results found i need to take at least 2 parameters matched results, if no results found i need to take at least 1 parameter matched results. For this scenario i want to write the search query using mongodb c#

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve it by using *Aggregate* is:

```
var sr = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1");
var db = sr.GetDatabase("Test");
var col = db.GetCollection<User>("MyUser");

var agg = col.Aggregate()
    .Project(p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        matchValue =
            (p.HomeTown == "Town 1" ? 1 : 0) +       // HomeTown condition
            (p.CurrentCity == "City 1" ? 1 : 0) +    // CurrentCity condition
            (p.School == "School 1" ? 1 : 0) +       // School condition
            (p.Company == "Company 1" ? 1 : 0)       // Company condition
        // matchValue will contains count of equal fields
    })
    .Group(new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, BsonValue>
    {
        {"_id", BsonValue.Create("$matchValue")},
        {"ids", new BsonDocument("$push", new BsonDocument("item","$Id")) }
        // Now I aggregate ids based on `matchValue`
    }))
    .Sort(new BsonDocument("_id", BsonValue.Create(-1)))
    .Limit(1)
    // Now I have maximum `matchValue` 
    .Unwind("ids")
    .Project(new BsonDocument("_id", "$ids.item"));
    // Now ids are available

// To gathering results I used below code:
var result = agg.ToList().Select(c=> c["_id"].AsObjectId).ToList();
```

Comment: getting the following error
Error 2 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<xxx>' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<xxx>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: MongoDB.Driver 2.4.2

Comment: I tested it with `MongoDB.Driver 2.4.2`, and it gives me expected results without any exception !? - Please add your code to your question ;).

Comment: the problem is i am using the legacy driver

Comment: If you mean you are using *[mongocsharpdriver 2.4.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/2.4.2)*; I test the above code by using it!!

Comment: So it should work! - I think there is a reference problem in your solution, I hope you can find its solution from SO by searching or asking it  ;).

Comment: i even updated my driver to https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver
still not working

Comment: i checked with https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/ it runs the query without errors but getting all the results in the collection